# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok here is an interesting one... I am receiving the 
warning: `Characters may not respond to 'addHeroType:atX:atY:fromMobTable'`

although I have the functions defined properly as far as I can see so how about another pair of eyes?

Here is the definition in `Characters.h`

```
-(void) addHeroType:(int)newMobType atX:(int)x atY:(int)y fromMobTable:(Mobdefs*)newMobTable;
```

Here is the function in the `Characters.m`

```
-(void) addHeroType:(int)newMobType atX:(int)x atY:(int)y fromMobTable:(Mobdefs*)newMobTable
```

and here is the call I am making in another class call heroFactory (`Characters.h` is included in heroFactory):

```
[Characters addHeroType:1 atX:location.x atY:location.y fromMobTable:newMobTable];
```

But this line causes the app to terminate due to uncaught exception - checking the debugger I see "NSObject Does Not Recognize Selector"

I am convinced that the issue is the wierdness of why I am seeing a warning that the Character class may not respond to the function call as written even though it matches identically to the definition.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void) addHeroType:(int)newMobType atX:(int)x atY:(int)y fromMobTable:(Mobdefs*) newMobTable
```

That is declared as an instance method.

```
[Characters addHeroType:1 atX:location.x atY:location.y fromMobTable:newMobTable];
```

But you are calling it on the class as a class method.

So either, declare the method as a class method

```
+(void) addHeroType:(int)newMobType atX:(int)x atY:(int)y fromMobTable:(Mobdefs*) newMobTable
```

Or call it on an instance

```
Characters *instance = [[[Characters alloc] init] autorelease];
[instance addHeroType:1 atX:location.x atY:location.y fromMobTable:newMobTable];
```

Depending on the scope your method requires, of course.